# Creating/Configuring Derby JDBC Client in IntelliJ Idea 13

Tags: java, jdbc, intellij-idea, derby

Sorry for this (maybe) stupid question. 
I need to create some local DB in my java project so I've decided for Apache Derby Client. I am working with **IntelliJ IDEA 13 Ultimate** and my problem is that I don't know, how to create local database.
Tutorials at Jetbrains websites aren't useful because there are articles only about connecting to the remote DB, not to the local one (or at least I didn't find them yet).

What have I done so far:

1. I've tried to set the DB up by creating new remote derby data source.
   Screenshot with the settings: [DB Settings screen](http://imageshack.com/a/img42/8805/ronb.jpg)

Username and password are the same: `admin`

1. After clicking `test connection`, this error is thrown: [error](http://imageshack.com/a/img823/6628/i8t5.jpg)
2. When I click `apply` and `ok`, it says that it's connected, but exception is still there.

So do you have any idea where the problem can be?
I've got small confiuration class called **DatabaseSetting.java**

```
package issuetrackinglite;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DatabaseSetting {

private String dbURL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/MallDB;create=true";
private String user = "admin";
private String password = "admin";
private Connection connection;



public static final String CREATE_ITEMS_DB = "CREATE TABLE items (item_id INTEGER NOT NULL, item_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, item_price REAL NOT NULL, multiplicity_shop INTEGER NOT NULL, multiplicity_store INTEGER NOT NULL)";
public static final String INSERT_PRODUCT = "INSERT INTO items (item_id, item_name, item_price, multiplicity_shop, multiplicity_store) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
public static final String CLEAR_ITEMS_DB = "DELETE FROM items";

// -------------------------------------------------------------

protected Connection connectToDB() {

    try {

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, user, password);

        return connection;

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("SQL exception - connectToDB(): " + ex.getMessage());
        return null;
    }

}
```

}

**EDIT**

Simply explained: I just need to create virtual derby database which will be created every time at the program start. 
I don't know, how to do it in IntelliJ.
I've added `DERBY_HOME` to the enviroment variables and also added path to Derby. Now this error is thrown by IntelliJ: [Error window](http://imageshack.com/a/img547/3540/8puq.jpg)

Thank you very much for your help and time

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've managed to get this work. Here are the steps that I've made to successfully configure local Derby database to work in IntelliJ Idea 13/14.

1. First, you need to manually start derby server (if it is not already running) before using it in IDEA. I usually do it via command prompt by typing:

   > C:\Users\PcName>startNetworkServer -noSecurityManager

   This command will start derby server on port number: **1527**. Make sure you have correctly set path in enviroment variables
2. Next go to IDEA, open **Database** window, click on the green plus sign in the upper left corner and in the dropdown menu choose: `Data Source -> Derby -> Remote`
3. You can inspire with my settings provided in the screenshot in my question. You can also download Derby driver files. IDEA does it just by clicking on the *download* button.

   Basic template which I always use is something like that:

   **Name field** should be in the form: `Derby - YourDatabaseName;create=true@localhost`

   **Host field** should have `localhost` inside

   **Port** has to be `1527`

   **Database field** has to be in form: `YourDatabaseName;create=true`

   **Urc to connect:** `jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/YourDatabaseName;create=true`
4. (Optional) - You can specify your database user name and password. In IDEA 14 there is a checkbox *Save on disk with master password protection*, which I personally always leave unchecked.

That's it. I hope this little guide will help somebody to configure Derby in Intellij IDEA

Comment: Yup this was perfect. I appreciate the guide.

Answer (score 1):

For embedded database, use the `default`/`In-Memory`/`URL only` select box on the right side of the connection URL input field. When set to `In-Memory`, it generates the following URL, which works for me.

```
 jdbc:derby:memory:MallDB;create=true
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that for a local (embedded) database, you would leave off the host and port in the connection url.

The [documentation](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/embedded_intro.html#sample_app) says that the url should be of the form: `jdbc:derby:MallDB;create=true`

Comment: Than You for Your answer.Trying to create an embedded DB didn't work. Error is still the same:  `Connection to MallDB failed. Unable to create database`
Maybe I'm not using the right tool. Or can it be some kind of privileges issue? The project directory is in `C:/Users/..`